# How to get Time offset information off datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, timezone-offset

I am converting a datetime[ns] column to a different timezone and the resulting column looks like this:

```
0   2011-05-25 20:30:00+02:00
1   2011-05-24 20:30:00+02:00
2   2011-05-20 20:30:00+02:00
3   2011-05-19 20:30:00+02:00
4   2011-05-15 13:30:00+02:00
```

I am trying to pull out the offset information, here `+02:00`.

```
offset = converted.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%z'))
```

But it gives me a blank column.

When the column is of dtype == object/str, the offest information disappears so can't put it out with regex either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
print (df)
                       date
0 2011-05-25 20:30:00+02:00
1 2011-05-24 20:30:00+02:00
2 2011-05-20 20:30:00+02:00
3 2011-05-19 20:30:00+02:00
4 2011-05-15 13:30:00+02:00

print (df.date.dt.tz)
Europe/Bratislava

df['timezone'] = df.date.dt.strftime('%z')
print (df)
                       date timezone
0 2011-05-25 20:30:00+02:00    +0200
1 2011-05-24 20:30:00+02:00    +0200
2 2011-05-20 20:30:00+02:00    +0200
3 2011-05-19 20:30:00+02:00    +0200
4 2011-05-15 13:30:00+02:00    +0200
```

If `dtype` of `date` column is `object/string` use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df['date'] = df.date.astype(str)
df['timezone'] = df.date.str[-6:]
print (df)
                        date timezone
0  2011-05-25 20:30:00+02:00   +02:00
1  2011-05-24 20:30:00+02:00   +02:00
2  2011-05-20 20:30:00+02:00   +02:00
3  2011-05-19 20:30:00+02:00   +02:00
4  2011-05-15 13:30:00+02:00   +02:00
```